# HTTPWebRequest Redirect Failing

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, http-headers

My Code Tries to navigate Url provided to it via external processes, but recently I found a bug in HTTPWebRequest Redirection
the URL in case was http://ask.bitauto.com/TreeAsk/index.aspx

What I found is this url gets NAvigated in browser successfully when HTTP-Referer is specified but .Net's WebRequest fails (without providing any exception) even when .Refer is assigned, in case of AutoRedirects Enabled is failed with MaxRedirect reached exception

According to MSDN

"If the AllowAutoRedirect property is true, the Referer property is set automatically when the request is redirected to another site."

does this mean redirects with in same site are handled differently. Please let me know if someone has any idea how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of this problem is within http://ask.bitauto.com/TreeAsk/index.aspx.

Following your link (thus having a referrer to stackoverflow) results in this answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2011 07:28:03 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Location: 
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 117
```

Notice the empty `Location` header - the reply from the server is a redirect to... nothing.

**Edit:**

It seems like the empty redirect page is only shown if you have no referrer or a non-ask.bitauto.com referrer. Setting the target URL as referrer results in a `200 OK` answer.

**Edit 2:**

The empty Location header behavior isn't according to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30), and it seems like different web agents react to it in [different way](http://snook.ca/archives/servers/empty_location).

I think the most robust solution for you is to specify [HTTPWebRequest.Referrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) in your request.

Comment: According to my understanding of HTTP Protocol empty Location Header means you are redirected to same page, so is HTTPWebRequest does but it is not setting Referer Header in this case, this situation results in same response from server again and again hence results in MaximumAutomaticRedirections.

Comment: I don't find any sources supporting that behavior of redirects, edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think you are right I was using AutoRedirect property of HTTPWebRequest, that resulted in problems.

I was following Manual redirect with Referer, after MaximumAutomaticRedirections were reached that behavior made HTTPWebRequest unpredictable and program crash.

Now following your advice I turned off AutomaticRedirects and its working fine.
Thanks for your advice!